# What is meaning of -vvv option in cURL request

Tags: curl, command-line-arguments

According to cURL documentation http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

> -v, --verbose
>
> Makes the fetching more verbose/talkative.

But I came across

```
curl -vvv -u name@foo.com:password http://www.example.com
```

What is the difference between `-v` and `-vvv`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**tl;dr**: there is no difference between `-v` and `-vvv`.

> Specifying -v multiple times usually means to increase verbosity accordingly.

This is true, e.g for a software like [memcached](http://memcached.org/):

```
-v            verbose (print errors/warnings while in event loop)
-vv           very verbose (also print client commands/reponses)
-vvv          extremely verbose (also print internal state transitions)
```

(behind the scenes the options parser [accumulates the level of verbosity](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/e73bc2e/memcached.c#L5155-L5157)).

But with curl command-line tool this is not the case. As you can see from [tool_getparam.c](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/a7999da/src/tool_getparam.c#L1688-L1699), passing `-v` simply *toggles* the so-called trace type to `TRACE_PLAIN`. Passing `-vv` or `-vvv` does the same.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to remember - vvv in most tools such as tcpdump is
"very very verbose"

It becomes a habit to use it with other tools even if it is no different than - v so that is why you may see it mentioned against cURL

Answer (score 3):

**explanation** : `-v` (`--verbose` flag) is useful for debugging and getting extra information about the response from server. ***Single v is just Enough***.

From [Curl documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-v) :

> `-v, --verbose`
>
> Makes curl verbose during the operation. **Useful for debugging and
>   seeing what's going on "under the hood"**. A line starting with '>'
>   means "header data" sent by curl, '<' means "header data" received by
>   curl that is hidden in normal cases, and a line starting with '*'
>   means additional info provided by curl.
>
> If you only want HTTP headers in the output, -i, --include might be
>   the option you're looking for.
>
> If you think this option still doesn't give you enough details,
>   consider using --trace or --trace-ascii instead.

Answer (score 2):

Specifying -v multiple times usually means to increase verbosity accordingly. So in this case you'd expect a very verbose output (-v specified three times).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be some sort of myth. According to Daniel Stenberg (the author of curl) [in this thread](https://twitter.com/bagder/status/1243149098636783618), curl does not and never has supported using more than one v to increase verbosity, but many people seem to think that it does.