# Power BI API returning 403 forbidden when fetching dashboard in My workspace

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I would try the Power BI API.

So I start by getting Embed Token ( I'm using application owns data scenario ).

**1.access Token**

```
var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token`,
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    formData: {
        'grant_type': process.env.GRANT_TYPE,
        'client_id': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        'resource': process.env.RESSOURCE,
        'Scope': process.env.SCOPE
    }
};

// get Access token from AAD to retrieve Embed Token in PBI API
let response;
try {
    response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, (error, response, data) => {
            if (error) reject(error)
            else resolve(data)
        })
    })
}
catch (error) {
    context.error(error)
}
```

**2.Fetch embed Token ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/dashboards_generatetokeningroup))**

```
var data = '{accessLevel:"View"}';

var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${process.env.GROUP_ID}/dashboards/${process.env.DASHBOARD_ID}/GenerateToken`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${JSON.parse(response).access_token}`
    },
    data: data
};

const embedtoken = await axios(config)

context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: embedtoken.data
};
```

**3. I have delegated permissions on azure**

[image]

I'm getting an embed token.

**4. fetch dashboard infos**

I'm using postman to fetch dashboard infos from the same group id and dashboard id that I mentioned in the api to get embed token

( I add that token in authorization section )

The problem is that I'm getting 403 Forbidden error.
[image]

PS: In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61061770/8107464) some limitations of service principal method are mentioned . is it the source of my problem ? Am I obliged to use `master user` method ?

[image]

Comment: In the title you said it is `My workspace`, but in the post you are talking about groups, so it is `A workspace`, right? Does the service principal has rights on it? For the test, change [tokenType](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics) in the embedded configuration to AAD and use the first token to authorize the embedding. Can you get the list of [dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/getdashboardsingroup) or [reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportsingroup) using it?

Comment: For testing I would try with dashboards then reports , 
Should I use access token or embed token ?

Comment: Test with the access token to prove that the service principal is set correctly.

Comment: ok but to understand , access token is it only to get embed token using service principale  ?

Comment: You can perfectly embed reports and dashboards using the AAD access token. However, this is something visible on the client side (it is JavaScript code running in the browser), so it is a security risk to expose it like that - it can be used to call the API and can do you harm. That why on the server side it is used to generate an embed token, which has shorter live, it is valid only for this particular report/dashboard and can't be used to call the API.

Comment: yes the AAD access token is working ! but why the embed_token does not ? as far as I understand, embed token is that same as AAD access token with shorter lifetime and permissions  ?

Comment: Now, when you narrowed the scope, it is time to start debugging your code :) We can't do that remotely. Check the rights over the dashboard and reports, is your code doing what you expect, etc. Every time when I had issues with service principal authentication, it was my fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of the usage of Embed Token. It cannot be used to call `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group id}/dashboards/{dashboard id}/` directly. AAD token is needed here.

To use an Embed Token, you should call the Embed URL with it.

The format of Embed URL is like:

```
https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=f6bfd646-b718-44dc-a378-b73e6b528204&groupId=be8908da-da25-452e-b220-163f52476cdd&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9XQUJJLVVTLU5PUlRILUNFTlRSQUwtcmVkaXJlY3QuYW5hbHlzaXMud2luZG93cy5uZXQiLCJlbWJlZEZlYXR1cmVzIjp7Im1vZGVybkVtYmVkIjp0cnVlfX0%3d
```

An .net example:

```
// You need to provide the workspaceId where the dashboard resides.
ODataResponseListReport reports = await client.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(workspaceId);

// Get the first report in the group.
Report report = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault();

// Generate Embed Token.
var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");
EmbedToken tokenResponse = client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroup(workspaceId, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);

// Generate Embed Configuration.
var embedConfig = new EmbedConfig()
{
    EmbedToken = tokenResponse,
    EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl,
    Id = report.Id
};
```

Then you can call the `EmbedUrl` with `EmbedToken`.

Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers#get-the-content-item-you-want-to-embed).