# Node js App integration with power bi rest Api

Tags: node.js, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

Is there a way using power bi rest API in node js, I watched video ,Ran Breuer and Arina Hantsis were showing the demo here,[Setting up and Getting Started with Power BI Embedded](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Setting-up-and-Getting-Started-with-Power-BI-Embedded) I want to achieve same but using node js, in our development environment we do not use c#.
I found the Node SDK but it saying we no longer support node SDK,[Node SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Node)

Do I have to change development structure from Node js to c#  in order to use power bi Rest API!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to achieve same, what Ran Breuer and Arina Hantsis demonstrate in there video!

you can use these codes...

after reading the documentation, I come up with this solution it took me 5 days to figure out,  anyway I am posting here so everyone can have easy access to codes.

**AppOwnData Power bi embedded reports **

Controller.js

```
 const request = require('request');

 const getAccessToken = function () {

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    const url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token';

    const username = ''; // Username of PowerBI "pro" account - stored in config
    const password = ''; // Password of PowerBI "pro" account - stored in config
    const clientId = ''; // Applicaton ID of app registered via Azure Active Directory - stored in config

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };

    const formData = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: clientId,
        resource: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
        scope: 'openid',
        username: username,
        password: password
    };

    request.post({
        url: url,
        form: formData,
        headers: headers
    }, function (err, result, body) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        const bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
        resolve(bodyObj.access_token);
    });
   });
  };

  const getReportEmbedToken = function (accessToken, groupId, reportId) {

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    const url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/' + groupId + '/reports/' + reportId + '/GenerateToken';

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    };

    const formData = {
        'accessLevel': 'view'
    };

    request.post({
        url: url,
        form: formData,
        headers: headers

    }, function (err, result, body) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        const bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
        resolve(bodyObj.token);
    });
});
};


   module.exports = {
embedReport: function (req, res) {
    getAccessToken().then(function (accessToken) {
        getReportEmbedToken(accessToken, req.params.groupId, req.params.reportId).then(function (embedToken) {
            res.render('index', {
                reportId: req.params.dashboardId,
                embedToken,
                embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=' + req.params.reportId + '&groupId=' + req.params.groupId
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            res.send(500, err);
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        res.send(500, err);
    });
   }
   };
```

Your router index.js

```
   const express = require('express'),
   router = express.Router(),
   mainCtrl = require('../controllers/MainController');
  router.get('/report/:groupId/:reportId', mainCtrl.embedReport);
  module.exports = router;
```

index.ejs or what ever you like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

    <head>
  <title>Node.js PowerBI Embed</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <style>
    html,
    body {
  height: 100%;
   }

.fill {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#reportContainer {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>
<div class="container-fluid fill">
<div id="reportContainer"></div>
</div>
<script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.js"></script>
<script>
const models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
const config = {
  type: 'report',
  tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
  accessToken: '<%- embedToken %>',
  embedUrl: '<%- embedUrl %>',
  id: '<%- reportId %>'
    };
   // Get a reference to the embedded dashboard HTML element 
   const reportContainer = $('#reportContainer')[0];
  // Embed the dashboard and display it within the div container. 
   powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
 </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Finally Enjoy

localhost:4000/report/put your group id here / put you report id here

Comment: Necro but, do you know if it's possible to just retrieve data instead of embedding?

Answer (score 3):

I used  @Joyo Waseem codes and successfully embedded the report, then I give a try to embed Dashboard and it works too, I decided to post my codes here so anyone who tries to embed Dashboard can use these codes.

**Embedded Dashboard using power bi Res API**

Controler.js

```
  const request = require('request');

   const getAccessToken = function () {

   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    const url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token';

    const username = ''; // Username of PowerBI "pro" account - stored in config
    const password = ''; // Password of PowerBI "pro" account - stored in config
    const clientId = ''; // Applicaton ID of app registered via Azure Active Directory - stored in config

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };

    const formData = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: clientId,
        resource: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
        scope: 'openid',
        username: username,
        password: password
    };

    request.post({
        url: url,
        form: formData,
        headers: headers
    }, function (err, result, body) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        const bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
        resolve(bodyObj.access_token);
    });
   });
   };

 const getEmbedToken = function (accessToken, groupId, dashboardId) {

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    const url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/' + groupId + '/dashboards/' + dashboardId + '/GenerateToken';

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    }; 

    const formData = {
        'accessLevel': 'View'
    };

    request.post({
        url: url,
        form: formData,
        headers: headers

    }, function (err, result, body) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        const bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
        resolve(bodyObj.token);
    });
    });
     };


  module.exports = {
prepareView: function(req, res) {
    getAccessToken().then(function(accessToken) {
        console.log(req.params.groupId);
        getEmbedToken(accessToken, req.params.groupId, req.params.dashboardId).then(function(embedToken) {
            res.render('index', {
                dashboardId: req.params.dashboardId,
                embedToken,
                embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/dashboardEmbed?dashboardId=' + req.params.dashboardId + '&groupId=' + req.params.groupId
            });
        });
    });
}
};
```

index.js

```
  const express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router(),
  mainCtrl = require('../controllers/MainController');
  router.get('/dashboard/:groupId/:dashboardId', mainCtrl.prepareView);
  module.exports = router;
```

index.ejs etc.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <title>Node.js PowerBI Embed</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <style>
  html,
   body {
  height: 100%;
   }

.fill {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

  #dashboardContainer {
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   display: block;
   }
 </style>
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid fill">
 <div id="dashboardContainer"></div>
 </div>
 <script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.js"></script>
 <script>
 const models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
 const config = {
  type: 'dashboard',
  tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
  accessToken: '<%- embedToken %>',
  embedUrl: '<%- embedUrl %>',
  id: '<%- dashboardId %>'
  };
// Get a reference to the embedded dashboard HTML element 
   const dashboardContainer = $('#dashboardContainer')[0];
// Embed the dashboard and display it within the div container. 
   powerbi.embed(dashboardContainer, config);
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: how can display embedUrl using javascript in Android Webview

Comment: @Jo Joy can you pls create one sample repo. ?  i follow as per this https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/NodeJS/README.mdGithub .. but not able to view the report.

Comment: I've my powerBI instance created in Azure. and i do added clientID, workspaceID, reportID, etc in config.json in node environment .. but stil facing issues.. kindly help me on this

Answer (score 0):

They no longer support the Node SDK, but have you tried it? It might still be working. You are gonna want some sort of SDK - it seems that is [not the easiest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35254559/3518108) API to work with.

Answer (score 0):

@Jo Joy what is the seen you should know .

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Node/issues/40

It about priorities these company decide in which project they do .

They can response very well about this. But as far as discussion there are no such plan to do so . You can access api before feb 2017 .

If newer api you have to try it for your . May be you folk it . We as commundity will contribute .