# Access Power BI API with Python

Tags: api, azure, powerbi

My requirement is to push real time data into Power BI using Python to first read from a database and then send the data inside a Streaming dataset in Power BI.

The first thing I want is to make a simple "get" call to Power BI.

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#oauth-20-authorization-flow) explains the processes of connecting to Power BI via the REST API for either a Client App or a Web App.
However, I'm using Python - not sure if that is either a client app or a web app.

Anyway, I am able to get the accessToken using the adal library and the method [.acquire_token_with_client_credentials](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/client_credentials_sample.py), which asks for authority_uri, tenant, client_id and client_secret (notice this is not asking for username and password).
By the way, I've also tried getting the accessToken with [.acquire_token_with_username_password](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/refresh_token_sample.py), but that didn't work.

Unfortunately, when I use the below code with the obtained accessToken, I get a response 403.

```
#accessToken is received using the adal libary 
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
read_datasets = requests.get('https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets', headers=headers)
#shockingly, this will result in a response 403
```

After reading other stackoverflow posts and looking at console apps, I believe the reason this doesn't work is because there is no user sign-in process.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341877/cant-get-client-credentials-access-token-to-authorize-power-bi?rq=1) mentions that using Client Credentials is not enough (it is enough to get the accessToken, but not enough to use the APIs)

Not sure how to proceed, but what I need is perhaps a way to keep using this [adal template](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/client_credentials_sample.py) that gives me the accessToken, and also to provide my username and password (if required), and together with the accessToken, to access the APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you've answered this over on the PowerBI forums:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Access-Power-BI-API-with-Python/m-p/190087#M6029

For future reference of anyone visiting this in the future:

Get your token using the python adal library and the appropriate method. Once you've got your token, you pass that in as part of your request headers like so:

```
    url = f'{self.api_url}/v1.0/myorg/groups/{self.group_id}/datasets'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.token["accessToken"]}'
    }
```

Where api_url is https://api.powerbi.com, group_id is your group_id and token is the token dict you got from acquire_token_with_username_password.

From there you'll be able to make all the PowerBI API calls you need.